# Unable to create application's shortcut on Home Screen upon installation in android

Tags: android, android-manifest, manifest, homescreen

I want to create a shortcut of the application on `home screen` when it is installed.

I added this to **AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<activity
        android:name="com.example.test.ShortCutActivity"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_short_cut" >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Also I have a Actvity created with ShortCutActivity name in my project.

**ShortCutActivity.java**

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ShortcutIconResource icon =
            Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this, R.drawable.ic_launcher);

        Intent intent = new Intent();

        Intent launchIntent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, launchIntent);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "ShortCut");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, icon);

        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
}
```

But it is not creating any shortcut. Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this sample code in your activity which is set as a LAUNCHER and MAIN in AndroidManifest.xml

```
private void createShortcut(){
     Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
     shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
     Intent intent = new Intent();
     intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
     intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "ShortcutDemo");
     intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));
     intent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");
     getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
}
```

Also apply following permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml

```
  <uses-permission android:name="com.android.launcher.permission.INSTALL_SHORTCUT" />
```

Hope this will work for you

Comment: This will only work when I launch the Application , I want the shortcut to be created when Application is installed

Comment: Actually this option is provided in developer profile at google market in setting option

Comment: we can create shortcut programmatically only after launching activity for first time

Answer (score -1):

```
Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);     
shortcutIntent.setClassName(this, this.getClass().getName()); 

Intent intent = new Intent();     
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);     
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, "hello");     
Parcelable iconResource = Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(this, R.drawable.icon);

intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE, iconResource);  
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_CREATE_SHORTCUT);

getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);
```